# How to update wordpress on docker

Tags: wordpress, docker

I'm running a php-fpm wordpress container.

The wordpress source files are mounted in a named volume "wordpress" shared with the Nginx container.

Everything is running well except when i need to update wordpress to a new version. The code inside the named volume persists. It is normal for a named volume...

I could manually delete the volume but there must be a better way.

My dockerfile:

```
FROM wordpress:4.9.5-php5.6-fpm-alpine
```

My docker-compose.yml

```yml
version: '3.1'

services:

  php:
    build: ./docker/php/
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - wordpress:/var/www/html
      - ./web/wp-content/:/var/www/html/wp-content/
      - ./web/wp-config.php:/var/www/html/wp-config.php

    environment:
      - DEBUG=${DEBUG:-0}
      - MYSQL_USER=$MYSQL_USER
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=$MYSQL_PASSWORD
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=$MYSQL_DATABASE

  nginx:
    image: nginx:1-alpine
    restart: unless-stopped
    expose:
      - 80
    volumes:
      - wordpress:/var/www/html
      - ./web/wp-content/:/var/www/html/wp-content/
      - ./docker/nginx/site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./docker/nginx/wordpress.conf:/etc/nginx/wordpress.conf
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=localhost

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.6
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
      - MYSQL_USER=$MYSQL_USER
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=$MYSQL_PASSWORD
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=$MYSQL_DATABASE
    volumes:
      - mysql:/var/lib/mysql

volumes:
  wordpress: {}
  mysql: {}

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: wordpress
```

Looking forward to reading your suggestions

Thank you

Answer (score 7):

When the  wordpress container comes up it checks for the existence of files at `/var/www/html` and copies only if not present. So in your case may you can update the `entrypoint` script to check the wordpress version in the `wp-includes/version.php` in the `/var/www/html` and the files in the container and then make a decision to replace the new files.

**Edit:**

According to [this](https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/blob/master/php7.1/fpm/docker-entrypoint.sh#L43) just deletion of `index.php` or `wp-includes/version.php` should copy the files from container again. Or may you can update your `entrypoint` script to copy files to `/var/www/html` all the time, but that may cause issues if you choose to scale the `wordpress` layer.

Comment: This seems like a pretty viable solution to me with a little tweaking to make it fit with your workflow.

Comment: Small correction: You need to delete both files (index.php and wp-includes/version.php), then recreate the image. I guess this has changed over time: https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/blob/master/php7.1/fpm/docker-entrypoint.sh#L48

Answer (score 6):

Thank you for your help.
It worked.
Here is the code i'm using.

I overriden the entrypoint in dockerfile

```
COPY check-wordpress-version.sh /usr/local/bin/

ENTRYPOINT ["check-wordpress-version.sh"]
```

Here is the content of check-wordpress-version.sh to check wordpress current version.

```
VOLUME_VERSION="$(php -r 'require('"'"'/var/www/html/wp-includes/version.php'"'"'); echo $wp_version;')"
echo "Volume version : "$VOLUME_VERSION
echo "WordPress version : "$WORDPRESS_VERSION

if [ $VOLUME_VERSION != $WORDPRESS_VERSION ]; then
    echo "Forcing WordPress code update..."
    rm -f /var/www/html/index.php
fi

docker-entrypoint.sh php-fpm
```

Answer (score 6):

Wordpress seems to have addressed this under [this issue](https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/issues/156).

I notice you are using a custom `wp-config.php`. Most likely, you can use the `WORDPRESS_CONFIG_EXTRA` for this rather than mounting `wp-config.php`.

Theoretically (per the link above), updating the image should update the database, but I have not confirmed.

Based on this, my `stack.yml`/`docker-compose.yml` looks like this:

```
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_CONFIG_EXTRA: |
        define( 'AUTOMATIC_UPDATER_DISABLED', true );
    volumes:
      - "./themes:/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/"
      - "./plugins:/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/"
      - "./uploads:/var/www/html/wp-content/uploads/"
```

Comment: Are you using a reverse proxy too (e.g. nginx)? In which case which volumes do you define for the nginx container?

Comment: I'm using jasonheecs/nginx-proxy. The only volume I have to define is for TLS certs per the documentation for the base image (nginxproxy/nginx-proxy).

Answer (score 4):

*It's easier solution.*

You have to edit `wp-config.php` file by add `define('FS_METHOD','direct');` to the end of file.
Save the file and run update. From now, you don't need FTP server to update your WordPress.

**Remember! Before update make a backup :)**

Answer (score 1):

To expend on @Bigbenny's answer, my Dockerfile looked like the following:

```
FROM wordpress:latest

WORKDIR /var/www/html

COPY . /var/www/html

COPY check-wordpress-version.sh /usr/local/bin/

RUN chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/check-wordpress-version.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/check-wordpress-version.sh"]
```

Two things to notice here:

1. I had to `chmod 755` the file or I would get a permissions denied error
2. I placed the script inside the `/usr/local/bin` because for some reason when I would just use `ENTRYPOINT["check-wordpress-version.sh"]`, the file wouldn't be found by the container.

I also, slightly tweaked the script to look like:

```
#!/bin/sh

VOLUME_VERSION="$(php -r 'require('"'"'/var/www/html/wp-includes/version.php'"'"'); echo $wp_version;')"
echo "Volume version : "$VOLUME_VERSION
echo "WordPress version : "$WORDPRESS_VERSION

if [ $VOLUME_VERSION != $WORDPRESS_VERSION ]; then
    echo "Forcing WordPress code update..."
    rm -f /var/www/html/index.php
    rm -f /var/www/html/wp-includes/version.php
fi

docker-entrypoint.sh apache2-foreground
```

For my use-case, I had to use `apache2-foreground` rather than `php-fpm`; I also deleted the `/var/www/html/wp-includes/version.php` file.

Finally, in my docker-compose, instead of the using the `image` directive; I used `build: ./wordpress`.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

> My answer applied to the official [docker wordpress image](https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress). So
> probably off topic but might help someone.

If you are using `docker-compose` you can pull the latest image using this command.

```
docker pull wordpress
```

I believe this will update your core docker image. Any other local project which you `docker-compose up -d` with this yml image setting as this will use the latest update.

```
  services:
    wordpress:
      image: wordpress:latest
```

If you currently running the image will you need to `docker-compose down` and  `docker-compose up -d` to invoke the update.

Answer (score 1):

It’s easier solution.

You have to edit wp-config.php file by add define('FS_METHOD','direct'); to the end of file.
Save the file and run update. From now, you don’t need FTP server to update your WordPress.
Remember! Before update make a backup

Answer (score 1):

When wordpress image is updated the image will not update wordpress itself but the php version. As wordpress can be updated via wp-admin and that is the recommended way to update wordpress even in docker setup. You can refer [this github discussion where it is explained](https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/issues/156). The [answer](https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/issues/156#issuecomment-419246648) which explained it.